# Define the order of attributes in dom

Tags: java, dom

I currently working on DOM and i wonder how can change the place of tags data 
for example

I have created element:

```
propElement = document.createElement("prop");
```

The prop is opening the tag.

Then

```
propElement.setAttribute("name", "name1");

propElement.setAttribute("name2", "name2");
```

The problem is that despite i put the set method name2 after name1 I will see in the tag name2 before name1.

How can I change the order ?

*(Note; I'm using a Java DOM API, not JavaScript.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, the order of attributes on elements is not significant. In fact, in a live DOM, there *is* no order. Order only seems to exist in relation to the *serialized* form of a DOM (e.g., HTML markup and the like). And even then, the order doesn't have any meaning except in relation to invalid text (more below).

Attributes are basically simple properties of an object (the DOM element to which they're attached). There is absolutely no order to them, and in fact the representation of them in the DOM is a [`NamedNodeMap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922) which is "...not maintained in any particular order."

It's important to remember that the DOM describes an object model. The *serialized form* of a DOM may be textual (for instance, an HTML document defining a DOM), but the DOM is not. In an HTML document, since it's linear text (top-to-bottom, left-to-right), naturally the text defining one attribute has to precede the text describing another, but that does **not** imply any kind of order to the attributes in the resulting DOM object, because they have no order at all. So this:

```
<div a="1" b="2">...</div>
```

describes ***exactly*** the same element as this:

```
<div b="2" a="1">...</div>
```

The resulting element is a `div` which has an attribute `a` with the value `1` and an attribute `b` with the value `2`.

This is exactly the same as setting properties on an object in program source. Consider some hypothetical `obj` with `x` and `y` properties. This code:

```
obj.a = 1;
obj.b = 2;
```

...results in **exactly** the same object as this code:

```
obj.b = 2;
obj.a = 1;
```

...provided `a` and `b` really are simple fields (not hidden function calls that may have side effects), which is true of attributes in the DOM.

There is one small way in which attribute order in the *textual* (serialized) form of a DOM may be significant, and it's only related to **invalid** text: If the same attribute is specified more than once, only the first value given is used, because it's invalid to specify the same attribute more than once. The values are not combined, and the subsequent value doesn't overwrite the previous one. The first one, only, is used.

So this **invalid** HTML:

```
<div class="foo" class="bar">...</div>
```

...actually results in a `div` with `class` `"foo"` (`"bar"` is not present at all). But this is just a coping mechanism for dealing with *invalid* serialized forms.

Comment: @FedorE: Okay. The answer doesn't change (doesn't matter what language you use, the order of attributes still isn't significant in the DOM), but that explains the tags on the question. :-)

Comment: Are you sure since now I saw that the order is alphabetical <tag a=a b=b> etc  maybe i need to create the document in different way ?

Comment: @FedorE: Yes, I'm sure. See the [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/). In particular, note that the in-memory representation of attributes is a [`NamedNodeMap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922) which is "...not maintained in any particular order." The particular tool you're using ***may*** put attributes in alphabetical order in some serialized format, but that has nothing to do with the DOM. Attributes on elements are just unordered properties of the element.

Comment: Hi TJ thanks for quick replay!!!I just put the order that I like for the property for instance propElement.setAttribute("b", "b"); propElement.setAttribute("a", "a") and the order changed to alphabetical order I opened the file in in IE and chrome and I used DOMSource source = new DOMSource(this.document);

  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");   maybe there is the problem?

Comment: @FedorE: Again: ***There is no order to the attributes in an element.*** The order can't "change" because it *does not exist*. I can't be any clearer than that. Anything you're doing where you're trying to dictate or rely on the order of attributes on an element, you need not to do, because they have no order.

Comment: Hello TJ sorry but maybe we are talking about something different and maybe I dont explain myself well ,**for sure **there is order and its alphabetical i create test program for it i you like i can post it you can see the same problem in this post http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/22079-java-xml-dom-transformer-attribute-ordering.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18914/discussion-between-fedore-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: @FedorE: (I don't do the chat thing when it's relevant to the question or answer; it's stupid of SO to try move important information off-page.)

Comment: @FedorE: Please read the answer and comments again. In a **serialized format** (such as an HTML file), which is linear, naturally the text describing one attribute has to come before the text describing another attribute, because of the nature of that **textual** format. But it's meaningless. `<div a="1" b="2">` defines ***exactly*** the same element with ***exactly*** the same attributes as `<div b="2" a="1">`. The text is different, but the DOM is not, because there is **no order** to attributes. As the spec I linked says, they're effectively properties on an object. *(continued)*

Comment: @FedorE: *(continuing)* Just as it doesn't matter whether you write `obj.x = 5;` followed by `obj.y = 6;` or `obj.y = 6;` followed by `obj.x = 5;`, because either way the object is the same and `x` is 5 and `y` is 6, it doesn't matter what order the text of a serialized format of a DOM has the attributes in, because the DOM object it describes is the same either way. So stop worrying about what order they come out in in a textual format, it's completely meaningless.

Comment: @FedorE: I've folded some of the above into the answer text.