# why doesn't element.attribute doesn't work in Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm creating a small quiz type application in javascript. My html structure looks like this.

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-insight" data-target="#myCarousel" data-responseID="1">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> 
  <h5>1</h5> 
  <p class="mb-0">label for 1</p>
  <div class="line-bottom gradient-purple"></div>
</label>
...
</div>
```

I'm trying to use the custom data attribute `data-responseID` to determine what answer was provided by the user.

When the program starts, loop through the labels using `querySelectorAll` and attaching a click listener to each one.

```
const responseLables = document.querySelectorAll('div.btn-group-toggle > label');
responseLables.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        const clickedResponse = element.attributes[2].value;
        determineWhereToSlide(clickedResponse);
    });
});
```

This works well in Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't in Edge. (I'm not concerned with IE 11)

determineWhereToSlide is just a function that gives an alert for now. Eventually it'll be used to push the carousel forward.

I've made a working example and you can see the issue if you open it up in different browser.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLmQKZ?editors=1010

I don't get why this is happening.

*EDIT 1

I just realized that the order of the attributes are different. If you change the index value to `...attributes[1]...` then it works just fine. Is there a better way to do this rather than providing an index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't refer to attributes by index (even if it seems it should work, attributes [were unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13160368/1048572) at least until DOM3). Use any of:

- [`element.getAttributeNode("data-responseID").value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNode)
- [`element.attributes["data-responseID"].value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)
- [`element.getAttribute("data-responseID")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)
- [`element.dataset.responseID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `getAttribute()` method.

replace this

```
const clickedResponse = element.attributes[2].value;
```

to this

```
const clickedResponse = element.getAttribute('data-responseID')
```

Comment: This answer is correct. But the other answer is more complete. So I accepted that. Regardless, I gave this response an upvote as the information is correct. Thank you Maxi.